# sort string-numbers

Tags: c#, string, list, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp)

I have a list with a lot of numbers in it.
But they are saved as strings because of some additional letters.

My list looks something like this:

```
1
10
11
11a
11b
12
2
20
21a
21c
A1
A2
...
```

but it should look like this

```
1
2
10
11a
11b
...
A1
A2
...
```

How do i sort my list to get this result?

Comment: Break the 'number' into components, then sort by that.

Comment: yes, natural sort is what ur after. this is a duplicate as stated by Jon. A good article on it at http://zootfroot.blogspot.com.au/2009/09/natural-sort-compare-with-linq-orderby.html

Comment: [Natural Sorting in C#](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting)

Comment: I confim that @Jason Jong solution pointed out is well working whereas accepted below solution doesn't sort as expected.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Going by the previous comments, I would also implement a custom `IComparer<T>` class. From what I can gather, the structure of the items is either a number, of a combination of a number followed by a letter(s). If this is the case, the following `IComparer<T>` implementation should work.

```
public class CustomComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var regex = new Regex("^(d+)");

        // run the regex on both strings
        var xRegexResult = regex.Match(x);
        var yRegexResult = regex.Match(y);

        // check if they are both numbers
        if (xRegexResult.Success && yRegexResult.Success)
        {
            return int.Parse(xRegexResult.Groups[1].Value).CompareTo(int.Parse(yRegexResult.Groups[1].Value));
        }

        // otherwise return as string comparison
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

With this `IComparer<T>`, you'll be able to sort your list of `string` by doing

```
var myComparer = new CustomComparer();
myListOfStrings.Sort(myComparer);
```

This has been tested with the following items:

`2, 1, 4d, 4e, 4c, 4a, 4b, A1, 20, B2, A2, a3, 5, 6, 4f, 1a`

and gives the result:

`1, 1a, 2, 20, 4a, 4b, 4c, 4d, 4e, 4f, 5, 6, A1, A2, a3, B2`

Comment: This is cool, but it doesn't correctly handle things like version numbers... 1.5.2, 1.9.9, 1.10.17

Strangely, Windows Explorer sorts this stuff correctly... but apparently the comparer isn't available to any other C# code in order to reproduce the same filename order as File Explorer will show when sorting by file name. Frustrating.

Comment: I believe the Regex should be `^(\\d+)`. Even better, the Regex could be just `(\\d+)` to handle `Region 1, Region 10, Region 2` as well as `1, 10, 2`.

Answer (score 10):

Since this includes many string operations, regex etc., I don't think it is an efficient algorithm but It seems to work.

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "11c22", "1", "10", "11", "11a", "11b", "12", "2", "20", "21a", "21c", "A1", "A2" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "File (5).txt", "File (1).txt", "File (10).txt", "File (100).txt", "File (2).txt" };
var sortedList1 = NaturalSort(list1).ToArray();
var sortedList2 = NaturalSort(list2).ToArray();
```

---

```
public static IEnumerable<string> NaturalSort(IEnumerable<string> list)
{
    int maxLen = list.Select(s => s.Length).Max();
    Func<string, char> PaddingChar = s => char.IsDigit(s[0]) ? ' ' : char.MaxValue;

    return list
            .Select(s =>
                new
                {
                    OrgStr = s,
                    SortStr = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\d+)|(\D+)", m => m.Value.PadLeft(maxLen, PaddingChar(m.Value)))
                })
            .OrderBy(x => x.SortStr)
            .Select(x => x.OrgStr);
}
```

Comment: Would love to see a version that actually handled version numbers... which have multiple numbers to keep in order:  2.5.7, 10.3.2, 2.18.3, etc.

Comment: this works great! thank you!

Comment: Was alerted to this thread when I asked a similar question and this method works flawlessly

Comment: This work great!.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you need to extract the number from each string and then sort the list of strings based on the list of numbers as keys. Do this in two steps.

To extract the number from each string, the simplest way I think is to use a regular expression - look for a match for `(\d+)` (if you have negative or decimal numbers, you'll have to use a different regular expression). Let's say you did that in a function called `ExtractNumber`

Now you can use some creative LINQ to sort, like this:

```
strings.Select(s=>new { key=ExtractNumber(s), value=s }) // Create a key-value pair
       .OrderBy(p=>p.key)                                // Sort by key
       .Select(p=>p.Value);                              // Extract the values
```

Comment: This looks like an elegant solution using LINQ, but what would happen when the iteration got to items `A1` and `A2`?

Comment: int.Parse((new Regex(@"(?<=pdf_)\d*?(?=_\.bmp$)")).Match(file).Value); // matches pdf_123456890_.bmp

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather new to C#, but here is a solution I appreciate in Java: you need to proceed in 2 steps, first define a customized IComparer and second use it in when calling the sort method. So you should be able to do something like:

```
public class MyListSorter : IComparer<MyObject>
{
  public int Compare(MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2)
  {
    if ( !Char.IsNumber(obj1) && Char.IsNumber(obj2) )
    {
       return 0;
    }
    else if ( Char.IsNumber(obj1) && !Char.IsNumber(obj2) )
    {
      return 1;
    }
    else
    {
      return obj2.CompareTo(obj1);
    }
  }
}
```

and then

```
myObjectList.Sort(new MyListSorter());
```

More infos on IComparer: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727

Comment: How on earth should `Char.IsNumber(obj1)` ever compile?