# How do I sort a list of checkboxes by their name?

Tags: c#, list, winforms, sorting, checkbox

I have a `foreach` loop which fills a list with `checkboxes` from a `groupbox`. Problem is that they are added in a random order. Since I named them all in an ascending alphabetical order I want to sort them by their `Name` propery.

I've already tried using `.Sort()` but it doesn't do anything. Also I tried using a Linq expression `DigBoxes = DigBoxes.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();`

But it also doesn't do anything...

Here's my code:

```cs
GroupBox box = (GroupBox)e.Argument;
string DigInput = "";
List<CheckBox> DigBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();

foreach (Control c in box.Controls)
{
    if(c is CheckBox)
    {
        DigBoxes.Add(c as CheckBox);
    }
}
DigBoxes = DigBoxes.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Define "doesn't do anything".

Comment: Where did you put the `.OrderBy`?

Comment: Could you post code with the `.OrderBy` as you've implemented it and a sample of the output? Seems weird that that wouldn't work.

Comment: By saying doesn't do anything that is exatcly what I mean. After it executes that line of code nothing changes when I'm checking with debugger

Comment: @Ziema I don't think you mean what you think you mean. Of course it's doing something, it's sorting the collection. You're just not using the result in a meaningful way.

Comment: I was thinking maybe my method doesn't apply to numbers. I've named my checkboxes like this: `CheckBox_Dig1_Value1`, `CheckBox_Dig1_Value2` etc. Can this be the problem?

Comment: It's most likely that your UI is not updating correctly to use the `DigBoxes` collection

Comment: @Jamie Rees No, I'm not trying to change the UI, I just need the list to be sorted in an alphabetical order.

Comment: @Aleks Andreev As I explained `foreach` adds all the checkboxes in a random order. So I'm trying to sort them by their `.Name` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going off of some information you provided in a comment about numbers being in the name, so I may or may not be off here..
Depending on how many you have, you will definitely see a problem. Sorting by `Name` is a straight string comparison, that is, it doesn't take numerical values into account the same way.

For example, suppose your collection consists of `CheckBox_7` and `CheckBox_10`. If you want those in numerical order, you'd expect 7 to come before 10. This isn't the case with strings. At index 9 of each name we have a 7 and a 1. 7 is obviously larger, which means as a whole, `"CheckBox_7"` is going to come after `"CheckBox_10"`.

If you want to take the numerical values into account, you'll need to parse the name and add a little extra intelligence into a custom sort method.
Here's one question with something similar. It might be a good starting point for your specific case: [sort string-numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988937/sort-string-numbers)

Comment: Thank you! I removed the numeric values in the `Name` property and replaced them with alphabetical ones and this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
var items = CheckBoxList1.Items
            .Cast<ListItem>()
            .OrderBy(i=>i.Text)
            .ToArray();
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Clear();
        CheckBoxList1.Items.AddRange(items);
```